# What openui5 layout to use for the content inside dialog(see UI prototype inside)

Tags: sapui5

Given that I have this dialog UI prototype with 2 buttons, what would be the best approach to program it?

[image]

My idea was to use Grid coming from "sap.ui.layout", but it is not perfect for the alignments.

[image]

So now I am thinking of using Flexbox for the first row,
then use table for the checkbox content and then again flexboxes for the rest of the rows.

Can there be any other better layouts that I am now aware of that I can use natively in openUI5.

Answer (score 3):

Layouts are a personal choice, but so far I found FlexBox to be the most convenient and easy to handle across device sizes.